# Add a row in a table with tablesorter jquery

Tags: jquery, css, row, tablesorter

I have a table buil with jquery library "Tablesorter" and I want add a row in this table when I click on a button but when I add the row , this does not take css of tablesorter .. so i cant select him, or the css "odd" "even" does not work ..

```
$("#ajouterCodePiece").click(function(){
    $('#tablesorter-demo-gauche tr:last').after('<tr'><td>'+$('#codepiece option:selected').text()+'</td><td>'+$('#mode option:selected').text()+'</td></tr>');
});
```

How can I do for add css and jquery of tablesorter in my new row .. thanks

Comment: you have mismatch of `'` at the start! `.after('<tr><td>' ....`

Comment: Any single quotes like this `$('#codepiece option:selected')` needs to be either escaped by backward slash  or replace them with double quotes   **" "**

Comment: Ok but my row is added at the table but there are not css of library tablesorter .. for example .. If I add row ==> it is added to table but I cant selected him, not css for "odd" or "even" etc ...

Comment: @user1814879: could you post the resulting html, so that we analyse on manual css inclusion to new rows

Comment: You can see the resuting html here : http://jsfiddle.net/t988C/11/ First one : If I add a row you can see that it's added but without a color .. and I can't select a row if I click it .. $("#tablesorter-demo-gauche tr").click(function(){
       $('#tablesorter-demo-gauche tr').not(this).removeClass('hilite');
        $(this).toggleClass('hilite'); 
        });

Comment: I have update code ==> http://jsfiddle.net/t988C/25/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tablesorter stores all of the table content in a cache, so in order to tell tablesorter that something has changed, you'll need to trigger an update:

```
$('table').trigger('update');
```

This this [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/t988C/33/)

```
$("#ajouterCodePiece").click(function () {
    $('#tablesorter-demo-gauche tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + $('#codepiece option:selected').text() + '</td><td>' + $('#mode option:selected').text() + '</td></tr>');
    $('#tablesorter-demo-gauche').trigger('update');
});
```

Comment: Thank very much . the row "odd" "even"  work but I can't select the new row .. you can see it here ... If you click on the row 1 or 2 it s ok http://jsfiddle.net/t988C/35/

Comment: Change your highlight function to bind to [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), like this: `$("#tablesorter-demo-gauche").on("click", "tr", function(){});` - here is the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/t988C/40/)

Comment: It's worrk weel .. Thank you